# getting 'values.map is not a function' error using angularstrap selectbox

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular strap  select box for displaying the options,
But i am not getting the options, error saying:

> values.map is not a function

How do i loop the options using angular **strap select box**

```
$scope.info = {"1":"1 - Cash","2":"2 - Clearing"} 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-model="info.value" ng-options="id as value for (id, value) in info"  bs-select>
            Action 
            <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently AngularStrap does not implement full `ngOptions` support. Looking through source code it seems that their select expects (see [source](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/4b81af5414015c9ccc7ed60af1da9abeafe36be8/src/helpers/parse-options.js#L50)) and array as values collection. I would recommend to use array data structure, which is anyway looks more convenient in this case:

```
$scope.info = [{id: 1, text: "1 - Cash"}, {id: 2, text: "2 - Clearing"}];
```

and HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
        data-ng-model="info.value" 
        ng-options="value.id as value.text for value in info" bs-select>
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and it was because I was initializing my `<select multiple>` ngModel with a string rather than an array.